# Number of perfect matching on sets of binary string

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n = 2k + 1$, consider all binary strings of length $n$ which contain $k$ or $k + 1$ number 1. Create a bipartite graph $G$ whose vertices are such strings, and there's an edge connecting vertex $u$ and $v$ if $u$ and $v$ differ by exactly one position. What is the asymptotic number of perfect matching on $G$?

I'm sorry if I use (seemingly) odd terminology, but this is my first time posting question on MO, and I'm just a first year undergrad after all.

Comment: Sorry, my typo. It's strings of length n. Fixed

Comment: The graph you are describing is a subgraph of the hypercube $Q_{n}$. It may be useful to start by looking at the hypercube and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but hopefully a few things to help get you started.

Your graph is sometimes called the *middle layers graph* and is a close relative of the *odd graph*.

A bunch of explicit perfect matchings (with some added structure) are found in this old paper: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~trotter/papers/62.pdf

For indirect methods, you can count perfect matchings of a graph using the permanent of its bipartite adjacency matrix.  A probabilistic approach may be possible, too.